# How do I make a foreign key value the same as the primary key value?

Tags: mysql

I've tried re-writting this question multiple times, and I can't seem to understand how to ask it.  I've been researching for the past 2 hours, and I have no idea if I'm searching the wrong things. I've read the MYSQL documentation on foreign keys (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). From my understanding, the foreign key points to the primary key, and the foreign key value should replicate the primary key value. This would be helpful for storing information that might be duplicate otherwise, so say a one to many relationship.

When I try to apply this to my mysql tables, I add a foreign key constraint to my second table pointing to the primary key of my first table. Everything else in my second table is nullable for the sake of learning.
When I enter a query into my first table, the primary key auto increments, however, the foreign key value (in the second table) is not updated to replicate the primary key.

I'm trying to grasp on if the foreign key relationship with the primary key is invalid/not working properly, or if out-right I need to manually query an insert command in the second table to replicate the first table primary key, and that the foreign key does not automatically replicate the value of the primary key.  If that is the case, what would be the point of a primary and foreign key if the values don't need to be linked/the same?  I'm really frustrated and feel idiotic because I don't understand the relationships of the keys after reading multiple pages from different sources.

Comment: The record in the second table (foreign key) is NOT supposed to get created automatically. You need to write code that adds record in the second table too. The foreign key constraint is there to ensure that you are not creating Orphan records, which means the integrity of the data is maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRIMARY KEY - FOREIGN KEY is a way to create a relationship between tables.  Consider these tables: Student, Course, Class.  For simplicity,

```
Student(StudentId, StudentName)
Course(CourseId, CourseName)
Class(ClassId, CourseId, StudentId)
```

In this case Class table has foreign key referencing Student and Course tables.  You can add new Student and/or Course, but it, of course, will not automatically add to Class table because a Student may not register to a Class.  A Course may not immediate have a Class because maybe, there's no instructor to teach.

A Class needs Students and Courses.  This is where the relationship is useful.  Student must exist in Student table before he can be added to Class.  Course must exist before Class can exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure a 1-to-1 relationship between the tables, so that adding a row to the first table always creates a corresponding row in the second table, you can use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the first table. It can use `NEW.id` to get the ID that was assigned to the new row, and then perform an `INSERT` on the second table to create a row there with that as the foreign key.